# How to close the SettingsPane programmatically?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

How can I programmatically close the [SettingsPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.aspx)?

Background: The user changes some setting in a settings flyout and I have to immediately react in the UI when the user closes the flyout. But the `SettingsPane` is still open, hiding app content. How can I close it from code?

Comment: not quite what you asked, but immediately reacting to a settings change doesn't require closing the pane (and that actually might be a unexpected/undesirable experience for user).  If the settings property being changed is bound to a view model, the effect of the change could be carried out without requiring the flyout be closed.

Comment: @JimO'Neil It's a connection setting. As soon as it is changed the user has to log in, so the app displays the CredentialPicker modal dialog (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.ui.credentialpicker.aspx). The settings pane overlaps it and the user has to click to make it go away.

Comment: ah ok... prior to bringing up CredentialPicker, can you just do a window.focus()?

Comment: interestingly, [WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701270.aspx) msdn documentation shows all flyout properties/methods including hide() but it is not available.

Comment: @Sushil It's not the settings *flyout* that is causing trouble. This one is dismissed by the user. But this leaves the settings *pane* open.

Comment: @JimO'Neil Good idea. No effect.

Comment: I had thrown a window.focus() call on the button in a flyout of [one of the samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49) and it did seem to close both the flyout and the pane, but I notice now it's showing the flyout programmatically and not initiated from the charm, still maybe tinkering with that sample would help surface a solution?

Comment: @jim I had the same problem again in another context (not in combination with a credential picker) - and here window.focus() indeed closes the settings flyout. Maybe the modal CredentialPicker made it not work :/